# Get the return value of stored procedure in JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures

I have written a stored procedure in mysql and calling it from Java code like below:

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("call proc(:data)").setParameter("data", details.toString());
List<Object[]> result = query.list();
```

I am returning a integer value from stored procedure. I need to extract the value and add it to Integer variable in my Java code. If I typecast to Number and use var.intValue(), it throws exception. Please help me in processing the return value from stored procedure.

Comment: Are you sure you should call list() if your query returns a single value?

Comment: I am new to Java. How to get single value as query result

Comment: I used uniqueResult() and my problem is solved.